# Regular expression to match last line break in file

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

In my quest to learn flex I'm having a scanner echo input adding line numbers.

After every line I display a counter and increment it.

Trouble is there is always a lone line number at the end of the display.

I need a regex that will ignore all line breaks except for the last one.

I tried `[\n/<<EOF>>]` to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In your quest to learn flex - please use the `flex-lexer` tag and not the `flex` tag. The latter is meant for Adobe/Apache Flex questions.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know what regex engine uses Flex but you can use this regex:

```
\z
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jD2zK6/1)**

> \z assert position at the very end of the string.
>
> Matches the end of a string only. Unlike $, this is not affected by
>   multiline mode, and, in contrast to \Z, will not match before a
>   trailing newline at the end of a string.

[image]

If above regex doesn't work then you can use this one:

```
(?<=[\S\s])$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jD2zK6/2)**

Edit: since flex seems to work slightly different than other regex engines you could use this regex:

```
[\s\S]$
```

To get the latest character of each line. Then you can iterated over all lines until get the last one. Here you have an online flex regex engine tool:

http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start

[image]

Comment: That's an cool site!  Thanks for the link.  Neither regex worked unfortunately but I like what you did there on the second one!

Comment: @MayNotBe I've updated my answer with an approach that might help you. Btw, I've added also a link to an online flex regex engine tool. Hope to help

Answer (score 2):

Try below regex, It will search for a new line character at the end of the line.

```
\n$
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that one too.  It picks up all new lines instead of just the last one.

Comment: This works for my case and selects just the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply doing:

```
\n$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DYi1cs7-EmbOd9Sv)

The `\n` matches the newline, the `$` matches end of string.

Comment: No dice.  It picks up all the newlines.

Comment: I am not familiar with flex. Could you provide some context as to how you're using the expression? Maybe post a code sample or a link to a function reference? I say this because if you're using something that is processing your input line by line and applying the regex to each line, then it's impossible to solve your problem with regex alone.