# How to extract only the last record from a csv file in APache NiFi

Tags: regex, etl, apache-nifi

I have a csv file which a new record comes and appends every 15 minutes. I need to extract only the latest record from the csv file and save as a JSON

I have able to extract the whole file and convert into a JSON, but I only need the latest record to be extracted and convert that record into JSON

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a regex for this working with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25588010/6456163):

```
.*(?<=[\S\s])$
```

You can see a working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kaf0le/1).